# NSPredicate to filter nested CoreData Models

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm having a CoreData models like bellow:

Country <---->>> City (One-to-many relationship)

Listed into a UITableView as section/row structure i.e.

===Egypt===
Cairo
Alexandria
Luxur
Ras AlBar
.
.
===Qatar===
Doha
.
.
.

Now I have UISearchBar that should allow user to filter the TableView based on the existence of the entered word within both **Country name OR City name**

So that if user inserted *'ar'* the following should show up:

===Egypt===
Ras AlBar
===Qatar===
Doha
.
.
.

Can't find any optimum query in CoreData to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController` for this. You don't mention whether you are but it makes it a lot easier to display `CoreData` into a `TableView`.

Anyway, the fetch for your `NSFetchedResultsController` should be on the cities. Not the countries. (Again, you don't say which it is but just in case).

So the predicate you can use is...

```
NSPredicate *cityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name [cd]CONTAINS %@", text];
NSPredicate *countryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country.name [cd]CONTAINS %@", text];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[cityPredicate, countryPredicate]];
```

Then when you use the `compoundPredicate` for your fetch you will get what you are looking for.

**How to set up your NSFetchedResultsController**

In your **CountryTableViewController.m** file

**1** - Create properties...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

**2** - Grab the Managed Object Context from your source...

```
self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

**3** - Add this method...

```
#pragma mark - fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"City"];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"country.name" ascending:NO];

    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"country.name" cacheName:nil];

    aController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**4** - For the method that filters the table...

```
- (void)filterResultsWithText:(NSString*)text
{
    NSPredicate *cityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name [cd]CONTAINS %@", text];
    NSPredicate *countryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country.name [cd]CONTAINS %@", text];

    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[cityPredicate, countryPredicate]];

    [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        //exit(-1);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**5** - Display the data

This will now set your data up, you don't need any more arrays.

To display it you can do...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForSection:(NSInteger*)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo title];
}
```

To get the country for at an index path you can do this...

```
Country *country = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will return the country at that index path.

There is a bit to set up but once you've done it once you will see why it is so easy.

Comment: that way I'll get an NSArray of Cities.. but unfortunately my UITableView structure is based on Array of Countries, each country (NSManaged) has Cities inside.

Comment: Like I said, you should be using NSFetchedResultsController. With the sectionPath of "country". Then you'll have the sections as countries and the rows as cities and not an NSArray in sight. I'll post some code to explain...

Comment: Edited my answer to explain the best way to do this. Whenever you are displaying CoreData information onto a TableView you really should use an NSFetchedResultsController. It makes displaying the information really easy.

Comment: Your solution seems great! But now you made me fall into another problem, which is how to map your solution to RestKit! Any Ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain in your original question and ill try to help.

Comment: I don't know whether this helps (or applicable) or not. But if you use AFIncrementalStore you wont have to manually call the REST Api. You will only be calling on Core Data API and AFIncrementalStore will call your Api in the background and your fetchResultController will be transparently updated in the background. Give it a shot if possible

Comment: @shadysayed I'm already using Restkit to interface between CoreData/API ... Adding AFIncrementalStore will be cumbersome.. But will consider in new projects.

Comment: @Fogmeister You solution works great! and I managed to map it to RestKit SDK. I only guess you missed one point -> NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Country"]; <-- "Country" should be changed to "City"

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out for you. It took me a while to understand NSFC but now I always use it with core data and tabkes.